# How to redirect user to another network if the first one is out of reach

Tags: proxy, squid

I am running squid proxy server which is connected to a network(Lets say A). I have another server running same proxy server but is connected to a different network(Lets say B). my question is, is there any filter or check in squid proxy server which I can use in A to check if internet is down or not, and if it is down then instead of sending user unable to connect to internet message, send the traffic to server B?

Answer (score 1):

You can try making browser to choose proxy using proxy.pac file, something like that:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    return "PROXY proxy3.company.lan:8080; PROXY proxy4.company.lan:8080";
}
```

Or you can configure one proxy as a fall back parent for another one if network infrastructure allows you to do this. For example: if A can't access internet directly then it tries to access internet through B. So it would look like: client -> A -> B -> internet.

Comment: I have access to Proxy server B but not A, so I will check out the first method you suggested but to make a failover proxy server would not be possible in my case